# Frequency count of values in a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, count

I have a python dict that I am trying to work out the frequency of which a value is listed.

I cannot import any additional classes so effectively need to write it from scratch.
So I have a dict() of

```
1: Dog, 2: Cat, 3: Dog, 4: Elephant
```

And I want to return something like:-

```
2: Dog, 1: Cat, 1:Elephant
```

This is what I have so far but I cannot work out how to get a count to work. I keep getting

```
0: Dog, 0: Cat, 0: Elephant
```

This is what I have so far, could someonle please tell me where I am going wrong?

It's obviously something to do with my count statement (this is just something that I found online but it clearly doesn't work.

I create a empty dict and then add values (animals) to it along with a corresponding key. I then need to go through all the values in all the keys to return the frequency.

The input is a dict() object that contains the values listed of 1: Dog, 2: Cat, 3: Dog, 4: Elephant

```
def frequency(self):  

    result = set()
    for i in self.items:
        result.add((self.count(i), self.items[i]))
    return sorted(result)
```

Comment: What are you counting from? A list of names? What's the input?

Comment: You are passing `self` to Frequency, so are you using a class here? What's the rest of the code look like?

Comment: The input is a list of names. I've updated the question a bit to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose your dictionary is named `d` and you want a count of the values:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {1: "dog", 2: "cat", 3: "dog", 4: "elephant"}
counts = Counter(d.values())
```

Now you can use the `counts` Counter:

```
counts['dog'] # 2
counts['elephant'] # 1
counts['fish'] # 0
```

If you must use custom code and classes for this instead of the standard library, I think your error is here:

```
result.add((self.count(i), self.items[i]))
```

What you may want is:

```
animal_name = self.items[i] #?
result.add((self.count(animal_name), animal_name))
```

Otherwise you may want to share with us what is in `self.items`...

Comment: Thank you but I can't import anything.

Comment: @Bob24 see update. If you don't share the class code it can be pretty hard to help you.

Comment: That's understood Reut. I shall ensure that my next post is clearer. However your code has worked a treat (although I'm not sure how). Excellent work, thank you. It's taken me about 2 hours of trying before I asked the question online. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {1:"Dog",2:"Cat", 3:"Dog", 4:"Elephant"}
count = {}
for v in d.values():
    if(not(v in count)):
        count[v] = 0
    count[v] += 1
print(count)
```

{'Dog': 2, 'Cat': 1, 'Elephant': 1}

Comment: the `if` condition can be written more simply as `if v not in count:`